# React map method return currentElement.name where name inside another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

Hi i  just want to render a table where name column name and its value dynmamically fetch from an api ..
and I store column value in an new array ;
I want to return rows value that link with column name in a row

```
const element = [ "ENDURANCE", "SPEED", "AGILITY", "STRENGTH" ] // this is my column name
```

api data of rows value

```
 
​
[
    {
        AGILITY: 1
        ENDURANCE: 1
        SPEED: 1
        STRENGTH: 1
        _id: "62c53266b631f27c54db8d89"
        date: "7/6/2022"
    }, {
        AGILITY: "4"
        ENDURANCE: "4"
        SPEED: "6"
        STRENGTH: "2"
        _id: "62c5a047a053c4ebb5de8c10"
        date: "7/6/2022"
    },
    ​{
        AGILITY: "8"
        ENDURANCE: "6"
        SPEED: "5"
        STRENGTH: "10"
        _id: "62c5a053a053c4ebb5de8c14"
        date: "7/6/2022"
    }
]
```

I just map this value in table dynamically
this is my code ....

```
 <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>/</th>
                        <th>Date</th>

                        {props.data.map((cur, i) => {
                          element.push(cur[0])  //store all column names
                          return <th key={i}>{cur[0]}</th>;
                        })}
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {props.stdata.map((curr, index) => {
                        
                        console.log(element);
                        return (
                          <>
                            <tr>
                              <td>{index+1}</td>
                              <td>
                                {curr.date} // date element is same in every api data
                              </td>
                              <td>{
                                curr[element] // may be this is wrong
                                }</td>
                            </tr>
                          </>
                        );
                      
                      })}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

this is how table  looks
[image]

Comment: curr[element] // may be this is wrong 
element is array of objects right? 

You can't display objects as children, only primitive values.

Comment: how can do this

Comment: You should display the elements inside of the array, not the array itself. 
In react, a common case is to use map function.  
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html read here

Comment: but currentElement name is dynamic

Comment: Then your description is not clear, what you exactly want to reach. 
If you receive data from API, you store taht inside of an array, then in some component map over them and display as element.

Comment: In simple word  i don't want to do     <td>{cur.ENDURANCE}</td>
                                <td>{cur.SPEED}</td>
                                <td>{cur.AGILITY}</td>
                                <td>{cur.STRENGTH}</td>
                              </tr>    so how ca i acheive this with different method

Comment: so, you have an array 
const arr =  ['ENDURANCE', 'SPEED']; 

you do this: 

{arr.map((item) => (
 <td key={item}>{item}</td>
))}

And you get as many tds as you need dynamically